# Inheritance: Reuse operator overload from friend class

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I have created a class Vector which is friend of the class Matrix. I am now trying to create a converting-constructor that vil set the vector to an invalid matrix if the matrix do not have the dimensions Mx1. In the solution to the exercise they reccommended to do it this way:

```
Vector::Vector( const Matrix & other ): Matrix() {
    if (other.isValid() && other.getColumns() == 1)
        Matrix::operator=(other); // reuse matrix' operator=

}
```

I understand basically everything except for the last line.
The Matrix() constructor sets any matrix to an invalid matrix, so to start with, "this" or the vector is set to invalid. But if the argument is valid and Mx1, then the vector will be set to other which is valid. But in the last line, why is there no *this= statement? How can I know that it is in fact the vector that is set equal to other?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking, but maybe you want to know how the vector is set to invalid matrix per default. Concerning this, note that the base class constructor is called before the body of the derived class constructor.

Comment: *I have created a class Vector which is friend of the class Matrix* - And you are calling the constructor of your friend class to initialize your class? Maybe you are confusing friendship and inheritance?

Comment: No, that is not what I am asking. As stated in the question, that part is perfectly understood. What I don't understand is how the line

Matrix::operator=(other); 

is setting "*this" (or the vector) equal to "other" when there is no obvious link between *this and "other".

Comment: @user6248314 You talk about friendship, but your code show inheritance, so there is a problem. In the context of your code, `Matrix::operator=(other);` is equivalent to `this->Matrix::operator=(other);`, which makes the link between `this` and `other`.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the terminologies. But yes,  I have no friend statement in mye class declaration, so we are dealing with inheritance.  Your comment answered my question anyways, so thank you very much;)

Answer (score 2):

`Vector` inherits from `Matrix`, and `Matrix::operator=(other);` calls the inherited assignment operator from `Matrix`.
(Friendship has nothing to do with this.)

`*this = other` (which is equivalent to `operator=(other)`) would call `Vector`'s assignment operator which presumably doesn't work in this context.